# SQL Server Analysis Services: Add Column to provide Sub-Total of row's group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Please find below my current SQL Query. What I'm trying to accomplish is add a column to the resultset that for each row provides the sub-total of the group that it belongs to. Can anyone provide me with an elegant solution to do this?

```
SELECT     costs.cost_des, SUM(costs_periods.actual) AS actual, SUM(costs.commitment) AS commitment, SUM(costs_periods.curr_bud) AS curr_bud, 
                      costs.exp_budget_limit, v_costs_by_group.cost_id, cost_groups.description AS groupDes, cost_groups.cost_group_id, 
                      cost_groups.parent_group_id
FROM         costs INNER JOIN
                      costs_periods ON costs.cost_id = costs_periods.cost_id INNER JOIN
                      v_costs_by_group ON costs.cost_id = v_costs_by_group.cost_id INNER JOIN
                      cost_groups ON v_costs_by_group.cost_group_id = cost_groups.cost_group_id
WHERE     (costs.year_id =
                          (SELECT     year_id
                            FROM          financial_years
                            WHERE      (year_des = @year))) AND (costs_periods.period <= @currentPeriod) AND (costs_periods.period <> 0) AND (costs_periods.period <> 13)
GROUP BY costs.cost_des, costs.exp_budget_limit, v_costs_by_group.cost_id, cost_groups.cost_group_id, cost_groups.description, 
                      cost_groups.parent_group_id
HAVING      (cost_groups.cost_group_id = @CostGroupID5) OR
                      (cost_groups.parent_group_id = @CostGroupID5)
ORDER BY groupDes, costs.cost_des
```

Many thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0):

1 You should do this in the Reporting tool

2 Read about ROLLUP and CUBE operator in SQL Server help file

Comment: Thanks for this, but I can't work out exactly where to place the ROLLUP operator in my existing SQL Query in order to get the desired effect. Could you point me in the right direction? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the WITH ROLLUP right after the GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY 
    costs.cost_des, costs.exp_budget_limit, v_costs_by_group.cost_id, 
    cost_groups.cost_group_id, cost_groups.description, cost_groups.parent_group_id
    WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: The problem with doing that is that it destroys the resultset order I have so neatly at the moment and add's in loads of extra rows which I do not want.